# the newest Mediatr and a handler with a synchronous method Handle: "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, .net, mediatr

I have the newest MediatR (12.2.0) and I have a synchronous method which returns nothing. Do I really need to use "async Task" instead of "Task"? Because the following method gives me "not all code paths return a value":

```
public class UploadFileCommandHandler(IFileUploadingService fileUploadingService) 
    : IRequestHandler<UploadFileCommand>
{
    private readonly IFileUploadingService _fileUploadingService = fileUploadingService;

    public /* async */ Task Handle(UploadFileCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _fileUploadingService.UploadFile(request.File); // <- this method returns VOID, not a task, see it below (the interface IFileUploadingService)
    }
}

public interface IFileUploadingService
{
    void UploadFile(File file);
}
```

I have to add "async" bur then I have the warning "async method lack of await". What is the correct solution?

Comment: Try something like `return await _fileUploadingService.UploadFile(request.File);`

Comment: I cannot use "await" because the method returns void

Comment: Either your Interface should also return a task with a response object instead of void, or your Handle() method should return void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the name ideally you should refactor `IFileUploadingService.UploadFile` to be async ("truly" async), since it seems to be an [IO-bound operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#recognize-cpu-bound-and-io-bound-work).

If the interface/implementation is outside of your control then usual approach would be to return [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=net-8.0) (though there can be edge cases):

```
public class UploadFileCommandHandler(IFileUploadingService fileUploadingService) 
    : IRequestHandler<UploadFileCommand>
{
    private readonly IFileUploadingService _fileUploadingService = fileUploadingService;

    public Task Handle(UploadFileCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _fileUploadingService.UploadFile(request.File); // <- this method returns VOID, not a task, see it below (the interface IFileUploadingService)
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```